# VB.NET Button with both MouseMove and Click/MouseClick handlers

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, click, mousemove

I'm attempting to to add both a `MouseMove` and a `Click` (or `MouseClick`) to a button. The end user needs the ability to click the button to add an element, but also the ability to drag the button to a specific location to add an element as well. I have both functions working independently. However, when I add both Handlers, the `MouseMove` takes precedence, and doesn't allow the `Click` to happen (attempting to click shows the `DragDropEffects.None` effect).

Button:

```
Dim Button As New Button()
'Button Attributes

AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf Button_Click
AddHandler Button.MouseMove, AddressOf Button_MouseMove
```

Handlers:

```
Private Sub Button_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Button.DoDragDrop("Button", DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'Add Element Function
End Sub
```

I've also tried it with the `MouseClick` handler, with the same results:

```
AddHandler Button.MouseClick, AddressOf Button_MouseClick

Private Sub Button_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    'Add Element Function
End Sub
```

1.) What is the reasoning behind the `Click`/`MouseClick` not able to fire when a `MouseMove` is implemented as well?

2.) What is the proper workaround to get both functions usable? Do I need to do `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` handlers, and track the distance that the mouse has moved to determine if I clicked or if I am dragging?

Comment: Drag & Drop requiires more than mousemove:  MouseDown, MouseUp and Mousemove with a bool variable to track the mouse state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CellDoubleClick event doesnt work after addition of Drag&Drop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3124099/17034).