# Is it possible to assign an event to a by code generated button in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, events, drag-and-drop

I am coding an Application to create a Mindmap like System. At the Moment I do that by Spawning a Button with specific text:

```cs
Button newButton = new Button();
this.Controls.Add(newButton);

ColorDialog MyDialog = new ColorDialog();
MyDialog.AllowFullOpen = false;
MyDialog.ShowHelp = true;
MyDialog.Color = Color.White;

if (MyDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     newButton.BackColor = MyDialog.Color;

newButton.Text = inputfield.Text;
newButton.Location = new Point(70, 170);
newButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
newButton.Show();
```

Now I am trying to assign a drag and drop function to it, and also have the code for it which is working, but my problem is that I cant assign a newButton_MouseDown event on it.

I tried this:

```
newButton.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.newButton_MouseDown);
```

But it doesn't work. I also couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Comment: What error message do you get when trying to assign the handler as you have listed here? Without having a complete and runnable example, it's hard to check, but the error messages will normally give you enough information to work out how to solve the problem. They're just not always obvious.

Comment: It simply doesnt work, it starts but dont work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3124099/celldoubleclick-event-doesnt-work-after-addition-of-dragdrop

Comment: @DrRuxton That should work fine, which suggests that something the button is sitting on is responding to the mouse click, then setting the `handled` property to `true`. Without knowing more about the structure of your program it's hard to be more specific. I'm assuming you're using winforms rather than WPF?

Comment: @DrRuxton - The link in Hans Passant's comment is the solution. The drag and drop logic is preventing the click event being fired. The link outlines a way to delay starting the drag operation until the mouse actually moves so click events should still be bubbled.

Comment: @DrRuxton
I created your case here and it worked perfectly. What version of .Net Framework are you using? And what kind of project, Windows Forms App?